# How can i make content to be expanded when we click on button?

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="collapsible"  data-collapsed-icon="carat-r" data-expanded-icon="carat-d" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">
            <h3>Escribir a InmoTico</h3>

             <form method="post" action="#">

                   <input name="im_name" id="im_name" 
                    value="1" >


                    <input name="im_web" 
                    id="im_web" type="text" value="2" >



             <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </form>
                    </div>
```

I am using jquerymobile 1.4.2.

When i click on submit button it displays a message like "underline fields are mandatory" or "form has been submitted successfully".

The problem is when we click on submit button  the expanded content is collapsing it self.But i  want this to be expanded when i click on submit.Please any one help me.

Comment: Finally i got a solution for it.For those who are using  jquerymobile 1.4.2 we have to use this function                     $( document ).on( 'pagecreate', function() {
   $("#submitid").click (function(){
   $( '#divIdToBeExpanded' ).collapsible( 'expand' );
   });});

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in click event as shown below

```
$('#submitId").click(function() {
    $('#divIdToBeExpanded').trigger('expand');
});
```

Comment: please any one help me in this

Comment: can u provide fiddle ? @user3350169

Comment: If you check this link http://b3.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=6cbb100090d21faa8db649229faa.  click on  "Current Residence and Pets". After that if we click on submit its closing autocratically,But i want  content of that to be visible